# Errors on logout of react-admin

Tags: redux, react-hooks, react-admin

When a user logs out, we get a number of errors in our components due to the redux store being cleared out before you are taken to the login page.

We have some components that use the useQueryWithStore. Here is an example:

```
const { data, total, error, loaded } = useQueryWithStore({
  type: "getList",
  resource: "tasks",
  payload: {
    pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 5 },
    sort: { field: "date_end", order: "ASC" },
  },
});
```

Then we are checking whether the data is loaded and there are no errors before rendering the component.

```
return (
  {!loaded && !error ? (
    <Loading />
  ) : (
    ...our component rendering data...
  )
)
```

The problem is that when a user logs out, it first clears the redux store before navigating to the login page. That means that both `!loaded` and `!error` are true and it attempts to render the component. But because the redux store has been cleared, `data` is undefined.

**How would you handle this best?**

1. Add default value to data? - `const {data = [], total, error, loaded}`
2. Check if data is undefined? - `{!loaded && !error && data}`
3. Use optional chaining? - Any references to `data` could use optional chaining - `data?.map(...map function...)`
4. Make pull request to change order of logout? - Instead of clearing redux first we could navigate to login page or logged out page and then clear redux store.
5. A better way I haven't thought of?

Thoughts?

Comment: Add default value to the data, so you would avoid adding the check in multiple places.

Comment: That makes sense in a general Javascript context. But with react, even with an empty array it will render the component. In a perfect world I wouldn't want that component to render if there is never any possibility of it showing to the user. Obviously if the user is logging out there is no potential for that component to be seen by the user.

Comment: React-admin 3.14.3 fixed a similar issue (see https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/6144). Does your problem still occur when you upgrade?